# How to make "int" parse blank strings?

Tags: python

I have a parsing system for fixed-length text records based on a layout table:

```
parse_table = [\
    ('name', type, length),
    ....
    ('numeric_field', int, 10), # int example
    ('textc_field', str, 100), # string example
    ...
]
```

The idea is that given a table for a message type, I just go through the string, and reconstruct a dictionary out of it, according to entries in the table.

Now, I can handle strings and proper integers, but `int()` will not parse all-spaces fields (for a good reason, of course).

I wanted to handle it by defining a subclass of `int` that handles blank strings. This way I could go and change the type of appropriate table entries without introducing additional kludges in the parsing code (like filters), and it would "just work".

But I can't figure out how to override the constructor of a build-in type in a sub-type, as defining constructor in the subclass does not seem to help. I feel I'm missing something fundamental here about how Python built-in types work.

How should I approach this? I'm also open to alternatives that don't add too much complexity.

Comment: +1... I'm trying to do something slightly similar in my project... currently instead of taking "types" though, I take functions that return the appropriate type. Thus, you can handle blank strings and *then* return an int.

Comment: Try replacing the int function with one you want to use instead.

Comment: How are you handling fixed-length string fields? Leaving the trailing whitespace in there?

Comment: @John Marchin, It's a format that does not contain variable-length strings.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use a factory function instead of int or a subclass of int:

```
def mk_int(s):
    s = s.strip()
    return int(s) if s else 0
```

Comment: Did NOT know you could have conditionals exposed after a return. Thankyou!

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra "a if b else c" is Python's version of the ternary operator, which looks like "b ? a : c" in many other languages. There is no condition here "after a return". the ternary expression is evaluated *before* the return statement.

Answer (score 60):

Use `int()` function with the argument `s.strip() or 0`, i.e:

```
int(s.strip() or 0)
```

Or if you know that the string will always contain only digit characters or is empty (`""`), then just:

```
int(s or 0)
```

In your specific case you can use lambda expression, e.g:

```
parse_table = [\
    ....
    ('numeric_field', lambda s: int(s.strip() or 0), 10), # int example
    ...
]
```

Comment: It's a lot cleaner, simpler, and easy to read. :+1

Comment: And what if I want to get `None`  (insted of `0`) for an empty string `''`? Thanks

Comment: @Confounded, expression: `int(s) if s.strip() else None`; function (lambda expression): `lambda s: int(s) if s.strip() else None`

Answer (score 6):

```
lenient_int = lambda string: int(string) if string.strip() else None
                                                          #else 0
                                                          #else ???
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when you do get an empty string, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

note that mylist is a list that contain:

Tuples, and inside tuples, there are 
I) null / empty values, 
ii) digits, numbers as strings, as well
iii) empty / null lists. for example:

```
mylist=[('','1',[]),('',[],2)]
```

@Arlaharen I am repeating here, your solution, somewhat differently, in order to add keywords, because, i lost a lot of time, in order to find it!

The following solution is stripping / converting null strings, empty strings, or otherwise, empty lists, as zero, BUT keeping non empty strings, non empty lists, that include digits / numbers as strings, and then it convert these strings, as numbers / digits.

Simple solution. Note that "0" can be replaced by iterable variables. 
Note the first solution cannot TREAT empty lists inside tuples.

```
int(mylist[0][0]) if mylist[0][0].strip() else 0
```

I found even more simpler way, that IT can treat empty lists in a tuple

```
int(mylist[0][0] or '0')
```

convert string to digits / convert string to number / convert string to integer
strip empty lists / strip empty string /  treat empty string as digit / number
convert null string as digit / number / convert null string as integer