# How can I get a blank quantity field to update as a 0 and stop my stripe payment from crashing?

Tags: django, checkout

I'm really stuck here and could use some help. When testing my project I found a flaw I'm having an issue fixing. In the shopping cart, if I remove the amount of any item and click Update Quantity:

[image]

...then I get the following error, and I would appreciate any tips or tricks. I'm thinking forcing it to update with 1 somehow?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Remove int() from request.POST.get('quantity') and add it to quantity variable when you use that variable in function. Because the request always contains string format, so ypu have convert it to integer after taking from html forms not at that time when you get it with POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out how to interpret an empty string as quantity, as that's causing the error.

More specifically, this should work: [How to make "int" parse blank strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941681/how-to-make-int-parse-blank-strings/2941975)

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring the quantity as 0 rather than None before implementation. This might solve the issue.

You have also not shown the snippet of the declaration of variable 'quantity'.

Try the following snippet in the update quantity function:

```
if quantity == None:
    quantity = 0
```